# Why is a formular in "Zend Framework" only saving "array" from Checkboxes?

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework

i try to get along with Zend for some formulars, which was easy and ok until i tried to get some "MultiCheckboxes" to work. Let's have some details:

With the following code:

```
    $this->addElement('MultiCheckbox', 'test', array(
            'label' =>'test',
            'required' => true,

            'multiOptions'=>array(1=>'hey', 2=>'ho')
```

));

But the only thing saved in the database is "array" as text, regardless which option (hey or ho) i check. I tried some things to change, but i don't get any change. It's always array. I guess i have a fundamental error in the beginning. I guess i need to get the multiOptions in a special way, before they are saved to the database.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Multicheckbox will give you an array of values since it allows multiple values to be selected. How are you saving this data and what do you want to be stored?

Comment: going to need to iterate through the array you receive then parse them to your db

Comment: @TimFountain: Yeah i guess that's the fact, i'm not sure how to save it. I want in the best way, that i save something like "hey,ho" in the databse if users select both or "hey" if only this item. Even 1,2 or 1 would be ok.

Comment: @VikingBlooded Can you help me with the word "iterate"? I'm not sure how to translate it in this context.

Comment: @le-grx see answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your output array, if you were to print_r it to the browser, would look something like this:

test[0] => 'hey', [1]=> 'ho'

But this is the same thing you would get with any array. so we can just simply iterate though our values here. We'll say that $output is the variable that receives the values from the submitted form.

```
foreach($output as $o){ echo 'This option is: ' . $o;}
```

That will echo out the value from the array as it iterates through the array.